# Footer with bottom menu is clear and text is running through it

Tags: wordpress, menu, footer

I have a fixed menu at the bottom of the page in the footer. This is fine, but with pages on my site where the text is too long to stay above the fold, the text runs right through the now clear footer. Strangely, the drop downs on the menu have a white background while the rest of the menu in the footer remains clear. The page text should scroll in its entirety above the footer, and the footer can be white instead of clear. Here is a page on the site which shows this:

http://lallabee.com/wordpress/?page_id=373

The code I used to get the menu fixed on the bottom is this:

```
body {
overflow: scroll;
}

#colophon {
bottom: 0;
font-size: 13px;
height: 35px;
position: fixed;
padding: 0 30px;
margin-bottom: 65px;
width: 100%;
}
```

I am using the Decode theme in WordPress.

Any help you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which browser are you having trouble with? It seems to work on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I put in a white background on the footer which looks OK, but the text is disappearing behind it. Maybe adding some padding at the bottom of the body text? Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes. If you want a fixed bottom footer and you don't want the end of the body text to go behind the footer, then you need to add margin to the bottom of the body tag that is the same height as the fixed footer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! This is the code I ended up with that works. I hope it helps someone else out there. I increased the height to make all my menu buttons appear in mobile.

```
body {
     overflow: scroll;
}

#colophon {
     background: white;
     bottom: 0;
     font-size: 13px;
     height: 57px;
     position: fixed;
     padding: 0 30px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

.entry-content {
     padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```